# Change my rectangle creating tool on html5 canvas without using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Here my full code on jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/6u7bLkwc/14/

Before exposing my problem, you can create a triangles on the image like this:

- Click on the image, then drag your mouse in order to create it.

**What is the problem with my code ?**

When i use this script, i have many lags on my PC ... especially for larger images !

**What i want ?**

Try to use my script without loop to prevent lags.

Issue come from this part of code:

```
function draw() {   
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
        var hue = Math.floor(Math.random()  * 360);

        ctx.fillStyle = shape.getColor();
        ctx.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
    });

    if (isMouseDown) {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(mouseDownX, mouseDownY, mouseX - mouseDownX, mouseY - mouseDownY);
    }
}
```

Exactly this line:

```
ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
```

This line is used to apply a background image to canvas ... since i want use this script for bigger images (Like 500ko and up) and loop it many time !!! this will create a self DDOSING attack to my computer.

**Why not use this line outside of draw function ?**

Because when i use it outside, and mouse hover the created rectangle ... i see a black background ... but like this i see my photo. (Mouse hover a rectangle make it transparent).

Any fix or any idea on how to fix it ? any different approch ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you exspierncing lag i mostly due to this function;

```
can.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    if (isMouseDown) return;
    var hoveredAlready = false;
    for (var i = shapes.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        var shape = shapes[i];
        if (mouseX < shape.getLeft() || mouseY < shape.getTop()
             || mouseX > shape.getRight()
             || mouseY > shape.getBottom()
             || hoveredAlready) {
            console.log(shape);
            shape.unHover();
        } else {
            shape.hover();
            hoveredAlready = true;
        }   
    }
});
```

By allowing the image to be hovered in your example with a single exsitsing rectangle it's fine but as soon as you have say like 4 and they overlap this function is being called about 100 times in less than a second so for some users they shall experience lag.

I managed to replicated your problem while trying to debug this:

[image]

Also removing the function while it does break the applications functionality does remove the lag.

Some things I'd consider doing to work back and eliminate lag, Sort out boundaries more efficiently so you know when the users cursor is within the boundaries and adjust for coming on and off the image or your going to get some really sideways looking rectangles, Consider how your transparency may affect multiple objects on different 'levels' and also consider minimizing the amount you write to console as that adds to the overhead.

Comment: The main reason is the image, with small image there no lags, but once we use big image the browser lag and nothing working ... this function is for rectangles only, that do not take place.

Comment: This function inside your fiddle you provided above is most certainly used, every time it has to calculate if a rectangle is visible and hoverable, Though from reading your newer posts I think you may have already changed the code pertaining to this..